# Howler jQuery stop all sounds when playing a new sound

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    const howlerList = {};

    for (var i = sounds.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
    {
        howlerList[sounds[i]] = new Howl({src: ["/sounds/" + sounds[i] + ".mp3"]});

        $("#" + sounds[i]).click(function() 
        {   
            howlerList[$(this).attr("id")].play();
        });
    };
});
```

Here is my code. The sounds are stored in a folder called sounds, and their ID is in a JSON file.

I am trying to stop all current sounds playing when a new button is pressed.

Changing to the code below will stop and restart the sound when that same button is clicked. But if I click other buttons then multiple sounds will play at the same time.

```
$("#" + sounds[i]).click(function() 
{   
    howlerList[$(this).attr("id")].stop();
    howlerList[$(this).attr("id")].play();
});
```

I want it to play just 1 sound at a time no matter which button is pressed. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried looping through all the howlerList elements and stop() them before playing the specific one they clicked?

Comment: No I did not, that is a good suggestion however Adam's answer below worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These three lines of code should stop the playback of all your sounds, including the currently playing one.

```
Object.keys(howlerList).forEach(function(key) {
    howlerList[key].stop();
});
```

`Object.keys(howlerList)` gets the keys of the provided object and returns them as an array. You then use `forEach` to loop through each item in the `howlerList` and call the `stop()` function, to stop each sound.

Added to your code, it could be used like this

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    const howlerList = {};

    for (var i = sounds.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
    {
        howlerList[sounds[i]] = new Howl({src: ["/sounds/" + sounds[i] + ".mp3"]});

        $("#" + sounds[i]).click(function() 
        {   
            Object.keys(howlerList).forEach(function(key) {
                howlerList[key].stop();
            });
            howlerList[$(this).attr("id")].play();
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: thank you very much, this worked. It says I have to wait 7 mins to mark as correct, so I will in 7 mins.

Comment: Glad I could help!